# How can I make same working code without contain matcher in ServerSpec

Tags: contains, matcher, serverspec

```ruby
describe file('/etc/checkfiles/server.cfg') do
  its(:content) {
    should contain("\/usr\/lib64\/nagios\/plugins\/check_procs -w 150 -c 200")
      .after(/command\[check_total_procs\]\=/)
  }
end
```

I'm using contain matcher like this code, but it will be obsoleted.
There is so many lines in 'server.cfg' and I want to check only 1line.
How can I make same working code without contain matcher?

Comment: The `contain` matcher is a custom extension to Serverspec with the custom chain `after`: https://github.com/mizzy/serverspec/blob/5cb12294775e02b53ff902687730bd279ff89065/lib/serverspec/matcher/contain.rb#L20. If you updated to the modern syntax/usage, then you would lose the `after` chain. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://serverspec.org/resource_types.html) note that:

> Instead of `contain`, you can use `its(:content)` and any standard rspec matchers. The matcher `contain` will be obsoleted.

I am inclined to say that this change may not have been properly thought out by the maintainer, and you might suggest to him that this feature should not in fact be deprecated.

With that said, though, it is easy enough to solve this problem just using regex:

```ruby
describe file('/etc/checkfiles/server.cfg') do
  its(:content) {
    should match /command\[check_total_procs].*check_procs -w 150 -c 200/m
  }
end
```

The key insight there being use of multiline regex `//m`, allowing you to say that one string comes after another in the file.